# Prevent website caching through metatags

Tags: html, caching

I have been done a quite lot of research on the internet discovering the influence and support of different caching metatags.

The following metatags cover all the browser support for not caching as been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/1976975):

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

After doing a lot of research I found that there are lot of contradictions in what people say. Some say the `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />` is not supported anymore after IE 6 and Firefox and Chrome does not ever support this.

Could anyone tell me or give me a clear explanation, perhaps with references (http vs https), which metatags are (not) supported in which browser? That would help me and I think other people as well! Thank you